# Open menu "add employee in orangeHRM"

Tags: orangehrm

please help how to open the add employee form in orangeHRM, i'm already add new record in ohrm_user_role_screen table to show it when we login as supervisor but the form add employee is not appear and on the screen display "Credentials Required".

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
orangehrm\symfony\plugins\cashmanCorePlugin\lib\role\SupervisorUserRoleDecorator.php

Add some role permission data to SupervisorUserRoleDecorator.php compare AdminUserRoleDecorator.php

orangehrm\symfony\plugins\cashmanCorePlugin\lib\role\AdminUserRoleDecorator.php

Like:

Add permission link for example 

const EMPLOYEE_REPORT_LINK="./symfony/web/index.php/time/displayEmployeeReportCriteria?reportId=2";

/**
     * Get the employee list ( whole employees )
     * @return Employee[]
     */
    public function getEmployeeList() {

        $employeeList = $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployeeList('empNumber', 'ASC', true);


        if ($employeeList[0]->getEmpNumber() == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return $employeeList;
        }
    }

    public function getEmployeeListForAttendanceTotalSummaryReport() {

        $employeeList = $this->getEmployeeService()->getEmployeeList('empNumber', 'ASC', true);

        $employee = new Employee();
        $employee->setEmpNumber('-1');
        $employee->setFirstName("All");

        if ($employeeList[0]->getEmpNumber() == null) {
            $employeeList->add($employee);
            return $employeeList;
        } else {
            $employeeList->add($employee);
            return $employeeList;
        }
    }
```